# Proof the Gauss lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

if $f(X)$ $\in \mathbb{ Z}[X]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb {Q} $, then $f(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb {Z}$.

How proof this , I don't know how start proof this problem 
Please help me 
Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the other way around,  and the statement as you have it would be trivial...  that is,  it should go :  polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb Z \implies $ irreducible over $Q$.

There is a proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) .

This was apparently included in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* (1801).